# Spring Data Mongo, why exception is not instance of DuplicateKeyException?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am working on `Spring Boot Rest MongoDB` example. In this example, I have `Student` collection, where `emailId` is unique field (I applied indexing where `unique=true`). When someone creates new Student and uses `emailId` already present in Mongo, I should get `DuplicateKeyException`. But somehow ex object is not part of the `DuplicateKeyException`. Why ex not instance of DuplicateKeyException?

```
try {
    studentRepository.save(student);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    if(ex instanceof DuplicateKeyException) {
        throw new DuplicateResourceFoundException("studentName already present");
    }
    throw new DuplicateResourceFoundException("studentName already present");


    //throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, env.getProperty("error.db.exception"), ex);
}
```

Comment: "I should get DuplicateKeyException." But what *do* you get?

Comment: If I get DuplicateKeyException I need to show another/Customer error message, if its not DuplicateKeyException, then throw whatever error I am getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this. I made the simple mistake import should have been done from `org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException`. Now this works fine.